# Open a MATLAB GUI from terminal

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am new to MATLAB GUI programming. I have designed a GUI using MATLAB GUIDE and saved it as a `.fig` file and I have written a `.m` file and linked both the files.

Now I start my GUI by opening MATLAB and then from the MATLAB command line I invoke it. This works fine, but now I want open my GUI directly from the Linux terminal command line by a command instead of opening MATLAB and then opening the GUI.

Is there a way to do it? I can't create an executable file, because I don't have MATLAB compiler tool box. How do I do this?

Comment: I am absolutely not sure about this, but since matlab gui is a part of matlab and since matlab uses a specific environment to execute code, my first impression is that you need to run matlab to be able to run matlab gui.

Comment: in windows i've written a batch file and i've run the file from desktop it has opened my GUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the MATLAB Compiler you cannot run your GUI without also running the MATLAB process. However, you can run your GUI without the MATLAB desktop showing, which I think is what you want. If your GUI main function is called `myGUI` you could run this command from a linux terminal:

```
matlab -nodesktop -r "myGUI"
```

MATLAB will still run in your terminal, so you might want to add a CloseRequestFcn that exits MATLAB. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#prop_CloseRequestFcn.

Comment: i'll try this and let you know

Comment: There's just been a really good write-up on all the ways to deploy your code see [http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/selecting-a-matlab-application-deployment-strategy.html](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/selecting-a-matlab-application-deployment-strategy.html)